# jQuery ajax does not call Servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Struggling on this one 2nd day.
I have a select-option form with list of tags.
I want to display articles from database depending on chosen tag. I have a div "showArticles", in my index.jsp, where I want to show articles.
I am using jquery and ajax for that purpose.
I wrote Servlet called test where I just output a simple string, but I cant even receive the text, seems that my servlet is never called. servlet is in package called "servlets",  I am using NetBeans.

This is the form:

```
                            <select id="b_sub_tag" name="b_sub_tag">
                                <option value='${0}'>Subject</option>
                                <c:forEach var="item" items="${subtagList}">
                                    <option value='${item}'>${item}</option>
                                    <c:set var="i" value='${i+1}'> </c:set>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
```

This is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$("#b_sub_tag").change(function(){       
    var option_value = $(this).children('option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "test",
                   data :"value="+option_value,
                   success: function(html) {
                               $("#showArticles").html(html);
                   }
           });
});
```

});

This is the Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "test", urlPatterns = {"/test"})
public class test extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        //response.getWriter().write("Omething");

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    response.getWriter().write("Smething");

}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

Ihave tried
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     out.println("Something");

as well, nothing.
I am writing output in doPost(), I tried to write in in doGet and processRequest, but no luck.

Anyone have any idea why this does not work?

---

### **Problem is resolved. I ve changed the code as follows:**

```
 $.ajax({
        url : "test",
        type: 'GET',
        ***data: {value:option_value},***

        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success : function(html){
           $("#showArticles").html(html);
           }
        }
    });
```

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        statefulb = (StatefulBeanRemote)     context.lookup("java:comp/env/StatefulBeanRemote");


        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("A text"); 

    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoadArticlesByTag.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the answer just as an answer and mark it accepted. Do not put it inside the question and put some weird tag in the title like as one would do in an old fashioned discussion forum.

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that I can add answer to my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is resolved. I ve changed the code as follows:

$.ajax({
        url : "test",
        type: 'GET',
        ***data: {value:option_value},***

```
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    success : function(html){
       $("#showArticles").html(html);
       }
    }
});
```

Servlet:

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

```
    final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    statefulb = (StatefulBeanRemote)     context.lookup("java:comp/env/StatefulBeanRemote");


    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write("A text"); 

} catch (NamingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LoadArticlesByTag.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try change your url to /test:

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/test",
                   data :"value="+option_value,
                   datatype : "html",
                   success: function(html) {
                               $("#showArticles").html(html);
                   }
});
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for reply. I have tried many variations, but no luck!

Comment: Although  $.get('test',function(data) { 
            $('#showArticles').text(data);}; works!!!